# Regular expression in PHP to detect extra/missing space in parenthesis

Tags: php

Assume the texts below:

```
(this is ) a ( text ) with(some) parenthesis(errors)
```

I am trying to write a PHP regular expression to detect grammar errors in parenthesis, in particular spaces.  The correct text here is:

```
(this is[no space]) a ([no space]text[no space]) with[missing space](some) parenthesis[missing space](errors)
```

note that I do not want to correct it, but just to return true/false and the function should be multibyte safe.

My current code looks like this but it does not work.

```
    $r = mb_ereg_match("\(\s\S", trim($str));
    $r = $r | mb_ereg_match(".\S\(", trim($str));
    $r = $r | mb_ereg_match("\)\S", trim($str));
    $r = $r | mb_ereg_match(".\S\s\)", trim($str));
```

Comment: No need for RegEx, _$result = strpos($str, '( ') > 0 || strpos($str, ' )') > 0;_ should do.

Comment: Thanks but this does not cover "parenthesis(errors)" case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `preg_match` we can try:

```php
$text = "(this is ) a ( text ) with(some) parenthesis(errors)";
if (preg_match("/\(\s+[^)]+\)|\([^)]+\s+\)|\w\(|\)\w/", $text)) {
    echo "invalid grammar detected";
}
```

Comment: Thanks how about multibyte safe?

Comment: Thanks again but this does not cover `with(some)` case where there is no space between `with` and `(`

Comment: That's not what your question is asking for though.

Comment: Sorry I added more details to the question, thanks again